# md-tab doen't accept height=100% to give all height of md-tab-group

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm having problems to adjust content of a tab to 100% of height of md-tab-group

For example:

```
<md-tab-group style="background-color: lightblue; height: 100%">// this works all bk is blue

<md-tab label="Info" style="background-color: indianred; height: 100%">//not work

<div style="background-color: yellow; height: 100%"></div>//with % not work, with px works

</md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

**EDIT:**
My problem is that `md-tab-group` expands his `height` to total of `height`. But the atribute `height` of `md-tab` doesn't fit to 100% of `md-tab-group`.

Because of that the content, even if I set the height to 100% it doesn't fit to 100% of `height`

If I set thet `height` attribute of the `<div>` to for example 500px it works correctly

I have this problem since I added `<!doctype html>` to my index.html

Versions: Beta.5
Angular 4[image]

The yellow block should be equal to green on height. In addition if you see, there are a scroll bar because the size of the yellow content overlaps the size of the yellow zone

What would be doing wrong?

Comment: Your question seems vague. Can you provide a little more info here.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I've edited the original post with more info

Comment: Is this what you want:https://plnkr.co/edit/zQSdL6UB5CDe3ZwyemHK?p=preview

Comment: Yes, but I want that `md-tab` height be the 100% of navigator window. On `md-tab-group` if you set height to 100% works fine but due to the `md-tab` height attribute, the <div> that is inside of `md-tab` doesn't works. On your plunker your `md-tab-group` doesn't takes 100% of screen height

Comment: I am sorry but I am seriously quite confused with your requirement now. Can you attach some snapshot of what you need.

Comment: Something like this:https://plnkr.co/edit/zQSdL6UB5CDe3ZwyemHK?p=preview

Comment: I've added a screenshot and more info

Comment: In your last plunker example your yellow div doesn't respect the height attribute.

Comment: See this:https://plnkr.co/edit/zQSdL6UB5CDe3ZwyemHK?p=preview

Comment: It has more height because div has content. If you remove the lorem content the height of the div dissappears.

Comment: So how much height do you want it to take?

Comment: From the start of tab to the end of green zone